# jQuery event manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'd would like to do something like backbonejs events, define an events object within the controller, something like this:

```
var UserController = function() {
    this.events = {
        'click .display': 'displayUsers',
        'click .delete': 'deleteUsers'
    }

    this.displayUsers = function() {
      //display users
    }

    this.deleteUsers = function() {
      //remove users
    }
}
```

After that, do something with requirejs and load the controller on demand and append the events, the code is almost ready but the events is something i can't resolve. Someone can help with any idea to do this?.

My idea is take the events object after controller class is loaded and send it to an event manager or something to create the events on the fly.